# Firefox renders identical dot com and dot net websites differently

Tags: html, http, firefox, browser

I have three sites: http://bidjunction.com/, http://www.bidjunction.net/, and http://bidjunction.net/.  The HTML/CSS is identical (see below) and in fact all three point to the same page.  Firefox 27.0.1 renders the first url as the largest, the second smaller, and the third even smaller.  Chrome and IE render them the same size.  What causes this?

```
[root@desktop ~]# diff <(curl http://bidjunction.com/index.html) <(curl http://bidjunction.net/index.html)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12543  100 12543    0     0  38881      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 73782
100 12543  100 12543    0     0  24839      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 64654
[root@desktop ~]#
```

Comment: What do you mean "render the same size"? Are you zoomed in?

Comment: @CodeCaster  The HTML is identical.  I am not zoomed in unless FF has some setting which states to zoom differently for .com and .net webpages.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but "works for me". Try running without plugins.

Comment: I think I found out why.  If I zoom in on a given url, close the browser, then open the browser, FF seems to remember the last zoom setting on a per ulr basis.  Does this seem logical?

Comment: Yes, remembering zoom level on domain name is how all current browsers implement it.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Please add this as a quick answer so I could select it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No thanks, I don't like low-hanging fruit that borders on offtopic. :-) Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per CodeCaster because he is too honorable for these types of answers.

> Yes, remembering zoom level on domain name is how all current browsers
>   implement it.